# PHP - SQL select Data display

Tags: php, sql

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv = "content-type" content = "text/html; charset = utf-8" />
    <title>Using file functions PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Web Development - Lab05</h1>
<?php
   require_once("settings.php");
   $dbconnect = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pswd, $dbnm);
    if($dbconnect->connect_errno >0)
    {
        die('Unable to connecto to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }

    $queryResult = "SELECT car_id, make, model, price FROM cars";

    echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Price</th></tr>";

    //initiate array 
    $displayrow= mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult);

    //initiate while loop to iterate through table
    while($displayrow)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Make'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Model'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($dbconnect);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is doing my head in, I cannot figure out why it will not display the actual data apart from the Table header. No matter what I used.
I have tried mysqli_fetch_array, mysqli_fetch_row, mysqli_fetch_assoc but nothing works.

Help and explanation why it was not displaying the data would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You can access data with coresponding column name. Change `$row['ID']` to `$row['car_id']`. and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Precision to names of field in Query ( car_id,make,...)

```
while($displayrow= mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult) )
{
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $displayrow['car_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $displayrow['make'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $displayrow['model'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $displayrow['price'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**First:** You aren't running a query, you are only putting the query text in a variable.  You need to use mysqli_query.

**Second:** You should add mysqli_fetch_array to the loop.

For example:

```
while($displayrow = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult))
{

}
```

Otherwise you are only getting the first row.

**Third:** Array keys are case sensitive.  There is no `$row['ID']`, as Jeribo pointed out, it is `$row['car_id']` as referenced in your query.  `$row['Make']` is not the same as `$row['make']`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query outside you still have to set it in the loop:

```
$result = $db->query($queryResult)

while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()){
...
}
```

a Good Tutorial is shown here: http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Answer (score 0):

$row needs to be initialized so why don't you try:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult))
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the result set first and then try fetching array from result set

```
<?php
   require_once("settings.php");
   $dbconnect = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pswd, $dbnm);
    if($dbconnect->connect_errno >0)
    {
        die('Unable to connecto to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }

    $query = "SELECT car_id, make, model, price FROM cars";
    $resultSet=mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query)
    echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Price</th></tr>";

    //initiate array 
    $displayrow= mysqli_fetch_array( $resultSet);

    //initiate while loop to iterate through table
    while($displayrow)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Make'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Model'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($dbconnect);
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp